# Warning: Implicit conversion loses Integer precision in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, warnings

I know it could be a duplicate, but i got about 30 **Implicit conversion loses Integer precision** warnings in my ios project after updating xcode to version 6.

First Example:

```
NSArray * stations = [self stationsJSON][KEY_ITEM_LIST];

int newSize = (stations.count + 1); // Implicit conversion loses Integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'
```

Second Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    int index = indexPath.row / 2; // Implicit conversion loses Integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
    ...
}
```

***I know what the warning means. Using NSInteger can help to avoid this warning.***

I don't understand, **why there was no warnings in xcode 5**? And why there is no warning after i change the line

```
int index = indexPath.row / 2;
```

to

```
int index = indexPath.row / 2i;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`NSArray count` is `NSUInteger`.

`NSIndexPath row` is `NSInteger`.

On 64-bit systems, `NSUInteger` and `NSInteger` are 64-bits but `int` is 32-bit. So the value won't fit which results in the warning.

It's best to avoid `int` in iOS. Instead, use the same type as the values you are dealing with.

```
NSInteger index = indexPath.row / 2;
```

You probably see these in Xcode 6 due to the default warnings. You can easily see these in Xcode 5 with the right warning settings and building for 64-bit.

Answer (score 40):

You can update project settings, to remove all

`Implicit conversion loses integer precision` warnings, by setting

`Implicit Conversion to 32 Bit Type` to `No`

in project's build settings.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't be the way to go for everybody but if you know what to do its a nice hint!

Comment: really handy for anyone working with Unity at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I was always annoyed by these warnings, so I came up with simple solution to avoid it:

```
@interface NSIndexPath(UnsignedIndex)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger sectionIndex;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger rowIndex;

@end

@implementation NSIndexPath(UnsignedIndex)

- (NSUInteger)sectionIndex {

    return (NSUInteger)self.section;
}

- (NSUInteger)rowIndex {

    return (NSUInteger)self.row;
}

@end
```

Simply use `rowIndex` and `sectionIndex` properties from this category instead of NSIndexPath's row and section properties.